# Predição com Redes Neurais TensorFlow

Tags: python, redes-neurais, tensorflow

Olá, estou com dificuldades para implementar uma rede neural. O meu problema é que só consigo implementar ela com um atributo **'X'**

Preciso de ajuda nesse código por exemplo, como faço para colocar dois atributos de entrada? No caso desse código só tem o atributo X eu queria colocar um outro atributo que também influencia a formula seila algo do tipo: **linear_model = W1 * x1 + W2 * x2 + b**

**Como ficaria o código?**

```
 import tensorflow as tf
    W = tf.Variable([.3], dtype = tf.float32)
    b = tf.Variable([-.3], dtype = tf.float32)
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    linear_model = W * x + b
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(init)

    squared_deltas = tf.square(linear_model - y)
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(squared_deltas)

    # Teste com aprendizado

    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
    train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
    sess.run(init) #reset values to incorrect defaults
    for i in range(1000):
        sess.run(train, {x: [1, 2, 3, 4], y: [0, -1, -2, -3]})

    print(sess.run([W, b]))
```

Comment: Sei que pode parecer um exagero, mas gostaria de te pedir para colocar o seu código aí. Se não, fica algo muito genérico.

Comment: @VictorStafusa passei abaixo uma descrição melhor com um código simples do meu problema! Obrigado.

Comment: Quando você diz "como faço para colocar dois atributos de entrada", você esta falando sobre adicionar mais classificadores para melhorar a margem de acerto da model? Ou de colocar diferentes dados para treinar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toda entrada de dados no TensorFlow é realizada com `placeholder`. Basta adicionar outro campo de placeholder

```
import tensorflow as tf

W1 = tf.Variable([.3], dtype = tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-.3], dtype = tf.float32)
x1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

W2 = tf.Variable([.3], dtype = tf.float32)
x2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
linear_model = W1 * x1 + W2 * x2 + b

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

squared_deltas = tf.square(linear_model - y)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(squared_deltas)

# Teste com aprendizado

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
sess.run(init) #reset values to incorrect defaults
for i in range(1000):
    dict = {
        x1: [1, 2, 3, 4],
        x2: [5, 6, 7, 8],
        y: [0, -1, -2, -3]

    }
    sess.run(train, dict)

print(sess.run([W1, b]))
```